# (MongoDB) Intersect the output of two query pipelines

Tags: mysql, mongodb, join, inner-join, aggregation

I’m trying to create a MongoDB pipeline that does the same as this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID FROM
  (Query_A) A 
  INNER JOIN 
  (Query_B) B
  ON A.ID = B.ID
```

I’ve come up with the following code to run both query pipelines:

```
[
    {
        "$facet": {
            "query_a": [...],
            "query_b": [...]
        }
    },
   ...
]
```

These pipelines return `ID`s and I want to get an intersection of these `ID`s ("$query_a.ID" equal to “$query_b.ID”).

**EDIT**:

The result of the `$facet` step is:

```
[
  {
    queryA: [
      {"ID": "c80ea2cb-3272-77ae-8f46-d95de600c5bf",
        "date": "1"},
      {"ID": "cdbcc129-548a-9d51-895a-1538200664e6",
        "date": "2"},
      {"ID": "a4ece1ba-42ae-e735-17b0-f619daa506f9",
        "date": "3"}
    ],
    queryB: [
      {"ID": "c80ea2cb-3272-77ae-8f46-d95de600c5bg",
        "date": "4"},
      {"ID": "cdbcc129-548a-9d51-895a-1538200664e6",
        "date": "5"},
      {"ID": "a4ece1ba-42ae-e735-17b0-f619daa506f9",
        "date": "6"}
    ]
  }
]
```

But my requested result is:

```
[
  {
    "dateA": "2",
    "dateB": "5",
    "intersection": "cdbcc129-548a-9d51-895a-1538200664e6"
  },
  {
    "dateA": "3",
    "dateB": "6",
    "intersection": "a4ece1ba-42ae-e735-17b0-f619daa506f9"
  }
]
```

Comment: Use `$setIntersection`

Comment: @nimrodserok I added the following:     {
        "$project": {
            "data": {
                "$setIntersection": ["$query_a.ID", "$query_b.ID"]
            }
        }
    },

Comment: Now I get the error: All operands of $setIntersection must be arrays. One argument is of type: string

Comment: Please add sample data which is the result of the `$facet`

Comment: @nimrodserok I added that as an edit to the question.

Comment: This is not clear. I can't tell from your example if this is a projection of 3 documents, where `$query_a.ID` is a single string on each one of them, **or**, if this is an array, and $query_a` is an array of objects, each containing `ID`

Comment: @nimrodserok $query_a and $query_b are both arrays of objects where each contains ID. I tried using $objectToArray in Edit 2 of the question, but I still don't get the desired array of IDs.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tv-yCbEhe8E) your situation? If not, please provide another link to the playground with your situation

Comment: @nimrodserok the $setIntersection worked now with your example. Thankt you! My original question is not fully solved yet, because it doesn't act like an SQL INNER JOIN. I want to access the other fields of "query_a" and "query_b" too, but they're not intersected based on the IDs like I wanted.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @nimrodserok here is the example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/YStfMDJrYFC. But I would like this output: {“intersection”: "a4ece1ba-42ae-e735-17b0-f619daa506f9", “dateA”: “3”, “dateB”: “6”}
{“intersection”: "cdbcc129-548a-9d51-895a-1538200664e6", “dateA”: “2”, “dateB”: “5”}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `$setIntersection` and then find the matching `dates`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      intersection: {$setIntersection: ["$queryA.ID", "$queryB.ID"]},
      queryA: 1, queryB: 1}
  },
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$intersection",
          in: {intersection: "$$this",
            queryA: {
              $first: {$filter: {
                  input: "$queryA",
                  as: "item",
                  cond: {$eq: ["$$item.ID", "$$this"]}
              }}
            },
            queryB: {
              $first: {$filter: {
                  input: "$queryB",
                  as: "item",
                  cond: {$eq: ["$$item.ID", "$$this"]}
              }}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data"}},
  {$project: {intersection: 1, dateA: "$queryA.date", dateB: "$queryB.date"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l3SUtKyJxO3)

Another option, since you want document per intersected `ID`, is to use `$unwind` and then `$group` to find common `ID`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      all: {$concatArrays: [
          {$map: {
              input: "$queryA",
              in: {ID: "$$this.ID", dateA: "$$this.date"}
           }},
          {$map: {
              input: "$queryB",
              in: {ID: "$$this.ID", dateB: "$$this.date"}
          }}
      ]}
  }},
  {$unwind: "$all"},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$all.ID",
      dateA: {$push: "$all.dateA"},
      dateB: {$push: "$all.dateB"}
  }},
  {$project: {
      dateA: {$first: "$dateA"},
      dateB: {$first: "$dateB"},
      intersection: "$_id",
      _id: 0
  }},
  {$match: {dateA: {$exists: true}, dateB: {$exists: true}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VNC-lQDUZzT)

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I hope I can integrate my other conditionals with this method.

Comment: I have another question based on using your example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73868497/mongodb-facet-using-group-works-but-changing-to-project-gives-the-error