# (MongoDB) $facet: using $group works, but changing to $project gives the error "$first's argument must be an array, but is object"

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation

I'm using a $facet to get an intersection of IDs from two pipelines. Using $group in query_a and query_b in the following pipeline gives the list of IDs.

Pipeline 1:

```
[
{
    "$facet": {
        "query_a": [
            {
                "$match": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "ID": ...
                }
            }
        ],
        "query_b": [
            {
                "$match": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "ID": ...
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "intersection": {
            "$setIntersection": [
                "$query_a.ID",
                "$query_b.ID"
            ]
        },
        "query_a": 1,
        "query_b": 1
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "data": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$intersection",
                "in": {
                    "intersection": "$$this",
                    "query_a": {
                        "$first": {
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": "$query_a",
                                "as": "item",
                                "cond": {
                                    "$eq": [
                                        "$$item.ID",
                                        "$$this"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "query_b": {
                        "$first": {
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": "$query_b",
                                "as": "item",
                                "cond": {
                                    "$eq": [
                                        "$$item.ID",
                                        "$$this"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": "$data"
},
{
    "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": "$data"
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "intersection": 1
    }
}
]
```

Example result printed using pymongo:

```
  {"ID": "c80ea2cb-3272-77ae-8f46-d95de600c5bf"}
  {"ID": "cdbcc129-548a-9d51-895a-1538200664e6"}
  {"ID": "a4ece1ba-42ae-e735-17b0-f619daa506f9"}
  ...
```

Changing $group to $project in query_a and query_b, so the list of IDs also includes not distinct values gives an error.

Pipeline 2:

```
[
{
    "$facet": {
        "query_a": [
            {
                "$match": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "ID": ...
                }
            }
        ],
        "query_b": [
            {
                "$match": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "ID": ...
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "intersection": {
            "$setIntersection": [
                "$query_a.ID",
                "$query_b.ID"
            ]
        },
        "query_a": 1,
        "query_b": 1
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "data": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$intersection",
                "in": {
                    "intersection": "$$this",
                    "query_a": {
                        "$first": {
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": "$query_a",
                                "as": "item",
                                "cond": {
                                    "$eq": [
                                        "$$item.ID",
                                        "$$this"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "query_b": {
                        "$first": {
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": "$query_b",
                                "as": "item",
                                "cond": {
                                    "$eq": [
                                        "$$item.ID",
                                        "$$this"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": "$data"
},
{
    "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": "$data"
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "intersection": 1
    }
}
]
```

Error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $first's argument must be an array, but is object, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $first's argument must be an array, but is object"
```

Running the queries in separate pipelines works using either $group or $project.

Query using $group:

```
        [
            {
                "$match": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "ID": ...
                }
            }
        ]
```

Example result printed using pymongo:

```
  {"ID": "c80ea2cb-3272-77ae-8f46-d95de600c5bf"}
  {"ID": "cdbcc129-548a-9d51-895a-1538200664e6"}
  {"ID": "a4ece1ba-42ae-e735-17b0-f619daa506f9"}
  ...
```

Query using $project:

```
        [
            {
                "$match": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "ID": ...
                }
            }
        ]
```

Example result printed using pymongo:

```
  {"ID": "c80ea2cb-3272-77ae-8f46-d95de600c5bf"}
  {"ID": "cdbcc129-548a-9d51-895a-1538200664e6"}
  {"ID": "a4ece1ba-42ae-e735-17b0-f619daa506f9"}
  ...
```

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: What aggregation is in `"$group"`?  What is `"$project"` within `"$facet"`?  Does one result in an array and the other not an array?

Comment: It works for me [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WyV3tY9QMvN) without unique ids

Comment: @rickhg12hs both have the same aggregation and give the same result. That is why I don't understand the error. That's the only difference in the code.

Comment: @nimrodserok I think the problem are not the unique or not unique IDs, but the output of $project not being considered an array like the output of $group. Do you maybe know a function that would help with casting/saving the output of the queries using $project as arrays?

Comment: I don't understand how the parameters for `"$group"` and `"$project"` could be the same.  `"$group"` aggregates whatever passes the `"$match"` stage.  `"$project"` will just "reformat/transform" whatever passes the `"$match"` stage.

Comment: `"$group"` must have an `"_id"` - what is it?  With `"$group"`, `"ID":` must have an aggregation operator - what is it?  In the `"$project"` version, `"ID":` has just `1`, or something more complicated?

Comment: The results of `query_a` and `query_b` are arrays, as these are `$facet` stages. Please provide sample documents from `query_a` and `query_b` results so we can help

Comment: @rickhg12hs I found the problem. I had to change {"$first": "$data"} to just "$data" when changing from $group to $project. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @nimrodserok I found the problem. I had to change {"$first": "$data"} to just "$data" when changing from $group to $project. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had to change `{"$first": "$data"}` to just `"$data"` when changing from `$group` to `$project`.